# Specific word or psychological term?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, psychology

What is the word or psychological term used for - "Start liking someone whom you hate as time passes, due to being forced to stay with them for long duration of time (say about 10 to 15 days)" - [Some situation like a girl starting to like the kidnapper after few 10 days of being kidnapped]

Please don't say the 4 letter "L" word :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably referring to the [Stockholm syndrome](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome):

> - **or capture-bonding,** is a **psychological phenomenon in which hostages express empathy and sympathy and have positive feelings toward their captors, sometimes to the point of defending and identifying with them.** These feelings are generally considered irrational in light of the danger or risk endured by the victims, who essentially mistake a lack of abuse from their captors for an act of kindness. The FBI's Hostage Barricade Database System shows that roughly 8% of victims show evidence of Stockholm syndrome.

Name origin:

> - **Stockholm syndrome is named after the Norrmalmstorg robbery of Kreditbanken at Norrmalmstorg in Stockholm,** Sweden, in which several bank employees were held hostage in a bank vault from August 23 to 28, 1973, while their captors negotiated with police. During this standoff, the victims became emotionally attached to their captors, rejected assistance from government officials at one point, and even defended their captors after they were freed from their six-day ordeal.

From:  Wikipedia

Comment: +1 - the only appropriate answer to the OP's example.